# SQL Function in databricks

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I have defined a function in SSMS and would like to have similar one in databricks but having hard time to find a right syntax.

My SSMS syntax is:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MaxOf5Values] (@D1 [int],@D2 [int],@D3 [int],@D4 [int],@D5 [int]) RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result int

    SET @Result = COALESCE(@D1, @D2, @D3, @D4, @D5)

    IF @D2 IS NOT NULL AND @D2 > @Result SET @Result = @D2
    IF @D3 IS NOT NULL AND @D3 > @Result SET @Result = @D3
    IF @D4 IS NOT NULL AND @D4 > @Result SET @Result = @D4
    IF @D5 IS NOT NULL AND @D5 > @Result SET @Result = @D5

    RETURN @Result
END
```

this is what I have tried but gives an error on `SET`

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION test(D1  INT, D2 int) RETURNS INT RETURN SET Result = D1 IF D2 IS NOT NULL AND D2 > Result SET Result = D2 Result SELECT test(1,25)
```

Comment: Is it the purpose of the function to find maximum of 5 values? If not clarify what it should do. Also, do you want to use Set and assign the value to a variable?

Comment: @SaideepArikontham yes, it should finde max of 5 values

Answer (score 0):

- According to the syntax of the create function as stated in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-sql-function), it might not be possible to set variables. You can either use expressions or queries.
- One way is to use an inbuild function directly i.e., the `greatest` function.

```
CREATE  or  REPLACE  FUNCTION test(a int, b int, c int, d int, e  int) RETURNS  int
Return  greatest(a,b,c,d,e);

SELECT test(1,2,NULL,10,5);
```

[image]

- Another way that you can do this is to use `CASE` statement. The following is the query that you can use:

```
CREATE  or  REPLACE  FUNCTION test(a int, b int) RETURNS  int
Return  SELECT  CASE  WHEN a > b THEN a ELSE b END;

SELECT test(20,3)
```

[image]